# struts2 Message resources values Split

Tags: struts2

Any suggestions for having multiple values in Struts2 resource messages as example

```
global.names=First Name#MiddleName#Last Name

<td><s:text  name="(global.names).split(\"#\")[0]"></td>
```

Is this possible  or any other Bright ideas

This reduces the no of additional key/values each in separate row

with regards
Karthik

Answer (score 1):

Waste of time and energy, plus you'd have to split it each time, or create a bunch of local variables if you only split it once, or loop over them, or...

Follow the normal Java property file conventions. You're trying to optimize something that doesn't need to be optimized. Organize using hierarchical names and use a decent property file editor instead.

Answer (score 0):

below code is to set value in "string" variable `'<'c:set var="string" value="'<'bean:message key="global.names" /'>'"/>`

below code is to print the split of "string" variable. `'<'c:out value="${fn:split(string, '# ')}"/'>'`

Comment: Hi
objective is to reduce the pairs in message resource to be used in Struts2.If to display on a Jsp page a standard set of 2 values.Be to set the pair in message resource
global.fname=First Name
global.mname=Middle Name
<td><s:text  name="global.fname" /></td>
<td><s:text  name="global.mname" /></td>

Same could be reduced to 1 Message using split
which would reduce the no of key values declaration in message resource of web application

global.names=First Name#Middle Name
<td><s:text  name="(global.names).split(\"#\")[0]"></td>
<td><s:text  name="(global.names).split(\"#\")[1]"></td>